# How to create pop up when user clicks phone number - iOS10 Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, popup

I have a IBAction where i am trying to make it so that when a user clicks this button, it prompts them with a pop up to either Cancel or Call the number. What i have below does not work.

```
@IBAction func PhoneBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: "1236541234") {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the `tel` protocol like this:

```
"tel://123651234"
```

Including this instructs the OS how to handle the URL. Implementing that, your code would then be:

```
@IBAction func PhoneBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: "tel://1236541234") {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

I would also suggest just using the `URL` API rather than `NSURL` with an eventual cast to `URL`. There is a string initializer for `URL` as well:

```
URL(string: "tel://1236541234")
```

Let me know if this helps.